# At least one object must implement IComparable. SortedSet C#

Tags: c#

in c# when using a sorted set data structure and using ICompare to sort the set by 
a specific value insert or adding work efficiently but when trying to get the min value in set raises  an exception My code

```
class priorityqueue
{
     public SortedSet<NODE> opendList;
    private class SortAccordingToTotal : IComparer<NODE>
    {
       public int Compare(NODE a, NODE b)
        {
            return a.TOTAL.CompareTo(b.TOTAL);
        }

    }
    public priorityqueue()
    {
        opendList = new SortedSet<NODE>(new SortAccordingToTotal());
    }
    public void Push (NODE N)
    {
        opendList.Add(N);
    }
    public bool search(NODE N)
    {
        return opendList.Contains(N);
    }
    public NODE POP()
    {
        NODE TEMP = new NODE();

        TEMP =  opendList.Min(); 
        opendList.Remove(TEMP);
        return TEMP;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example testcase where this exception is thrown?

Comment: `Min` is a property, not a method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411719(v=vs.110).aspx), so try changing `opendList.Min()` with `opendList.Min` and it should work.

Comment: Should not be the problem since Min() is also an extension method on IEnumerable https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd411939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @SamSegers It should still be changed.  Using the `IEnumerable` extension method would force a full linear search, rather than a binary search.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure about that, the documentation says it's overloaded. Although I can not find immediately the sourcecode to confirm this. I know we should encourage using the property anyway but we're looking for his problem here.

Comment: @SamSegers It would be impossible to do anything other than a linear search given the API exposed by `IEnumerable`.  It would be impossible to do a linear search, even if you knew the sequence was sorted, as you can't access items by index.

Comment: Thank you all 
can you tell me how to compare two 2d array ?? 
thanks in advance

Comment: @Servy note that the type is `SortedSet`, if there exists an extension method like `public static T Min<T>(this SortedSet<T> set){return set.Min;}` this will be used above the `IEnumerable` implementation, no?

Comment: @SamSegers But there is no such extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment from @Claudiu Georgiu, the [`Min` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411719(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `SortedSet` should leverage your custom comparer.  However, the [`Min()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd411939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you are likely currently using, requires that your `NODE` class implement either the  `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` interface.  If you switch to calling the property, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty ambiguous, but it sounds like your NODE class needs to implement the IComparable interface.  Luckily, doing so is easy.

```
public class NODE: IComparable
{
    public int total{ get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;
        var otherNode = obj as Hobby;
        return this.total.CompareTo(otherNode.total);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should not since it is using an IComparer for his SortedSet